# How to implement save dark theme with local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage

I'm trying to implement a dark theme that once the user refreshes the page or closes the browser, it would keep that setting until the user decides to change it. How would I implement that with local storage? I've never used it. Your help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
function change() {
  var element = document.body;
  element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
}
```

```css
body{background:white; color:black; transition:0.3; }

.dark-mode{color:white; transition:0.3s; background:black;}
```

```html
<button onclick="change()">dark</button>

<p>Some text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact you never used it is not excuse to not even try it, just saying for next time....

Documentation and usage is simple as it gets.

```
    function change() {
      var element = document.body;
      element.classList.toggle("dark-mode");
    
      if (element.classList.contains("dark-mode")) {
     //if class was added to body
        localStorage.setItem("background", "dark-mode");
     //save information in "background" localStorage variable, use dark-mode class name
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("background", "");
    //if class was removed set background" localStorage variable to null
      }
    }
    
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
//when loading document
      var background = localStorage.getItem("background");
    // get localStorage var background
      if (background) {
    // if its not null and empty
        document.body.className += background;
    //add class to body
      }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining how it works. This certainly helps me study the code and learn it.

Comment: @Majora   You should consider marking one of the answers as accepted to mark this question as solved...

Answer (score 0):

Like Mohit/ikiK says you need to use a conditional and check for the browser localStorage, remember:

**localStorage.getItem(keyName)**: Get a value stored on browser storage 
**localStorage.setItem(keyName, value)**: Set a value to browser storage